# How use offline maps google in my application

Tags: android, google-maps

I try to do an android application in which when a press a button then application display offline google maps with route for exmaple between berlin and paris.
I want to do the same as in osmdroid where can select map fragment(using mobile atlas creator) and save to file.And next display this map offline. Is the possible in maps google??

Answer (score 0):

Check [offline-google-maps-on-osmdroid](http://datamoil.blogspot.in/2011/05/offline-google-maps-on-osmdroid.html).

The map container is **OSMDroid**.

Comment: But how use it?? COuld you write step by step how do this?? I try do it but my application doesn't work?? Wchich code should I write in layout and in Activity ??